# "Your shell has not been properly configured" in DeepFake

Tags: shell

During the setup of DeepFaceLab,
I wanted to use a shell script to run conda activate, so I created a shell script named test1.bash as follows.
I already try "conda init" but shell return "Noaction" and nothing change.I also try [this](https://github.com/nagadit/DeepFaceLab_Linux/issues/29) but it doesn't change.I think my driver is something  wrong but what do you think??
↓this is my computer. I would appreciate if someone teach me solution.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
NVIDIA
17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102GL [Quadro RTX 6000/8000] (rev a1)
17:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
17:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
17:00.3 Serial bus controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
```

The error follows:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what to do. What happened when you tried it? ([Edit] that info into the question, don't just add a comment).

Comment: Sorry. When I did →
"bash 1_clear_workspace.sh"
then I got this error